# Counting the number of ways a marksman can shoot $8$ targets down entirely

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

> In a shooting match, eight clay targets are arranged in two hanging columns of three targets each and one column of two targets. A marksman is to break all the targets according to the following rules:
>
> 1. The marksman first chooses a column from which a target is to be broken.
> 2. The marksman must then break the lowest remaining target in the chosen column.
>
> If the rules are followed, in how many different orders can the eight targets be broken? ([source](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/1990_AIME_Problems/Problem_8))

I think, the solution disregards the second condition.

Let us call $3$ columns $A$ ($3$ targets), $B$ ($2$ targets) and $C$ ($3$ targets).
And the targets $3a$, $2a$, $a$ in $A$; $2b$, $b$ in $B$ and $3c$, $2c$, $c$ in $C$, the targets written in order from the lowest to the highest.

We need to count the number of ways in which the abovementioned targets can be arranged so that $3a$ comes before $2a$ and $2a$ before $a$, and similarly with targets in $B$ and $C$, which I am unable to. (Example: $3a, 2c, 2a, a, 3b, c, 2b, b$)

**Questions**

1. Is my approach correct? How can it be completed?
2. Is the source's solution *really* disregarding the second condition?

Comment: Think of hitting (picking) its column instead of the target (the target is fixed to be the lowest one). This is equivalent to arranging the labels of columns $aaabbbcc$.

Comment: @cosmo5 Oh, now it makes sense! Is there a way to finish my approach?

Comment: As hinted, name the identical targets $a,a,a,b,\ldots$ instead of $a,2a,3a,b,\ldots$. Then all possibilities correspond to distinct arrangements of $aaabbcc$ as done in the source solution. See also the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

You have $8!$ total ways to shoot w/o considering conditions

But considering only column $A$, you can't shoot in $3!$ ways, you can shoot only in **one** way, from lowest to highest, so divide by $3!$

Same argument for columns $B$ and $C$, thus putting it all together,

Permissible # of ways = $\dfrac{8!}{3!2!3!}$

You should now be able to answer the queries you have raised